# Applying changes to column values in R with mutate()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

After searching for an existing solution on StackOverflow, I decided to ask it here.

I have a column ("time_as_dec") in a dataframe

[image]

that I am trying to populate via a custom function:

```
datetime_to_time_as_decimal <- function(dt) {

  hour_part <- format(as.POSIXct(dt,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"%H")
  minutes_part <- format(as.POSIXct(dt,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"%M")
  result <- as.numeric(hour_part) + as.numeric(minutes_part)/60
  
  return(result)
  
}
```

When I run the following, I get the expected console output but the update to the column does not occur.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(datetime) %>%
  mutate(
    time_as_dec = datetime_to_time_as_decimal(datetime)
  )
```

**Partial Result**

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You still need to assign results with `dplyr`. If you want `df` to change, then start the line with `df <- df %>% ...`.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion by Gregor in the comments, I was able to correct and then  refactor to this:

```
    df <- df %>%
          mutate(time_as_dec=datetime_to_time_as_decimal(df$datetime))
```

Thanks